# AngularJS - using ngRoute - after navigation page dissapears

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on AngularJS based website.
Have ngRoute set up and everything worked OK so far. 
I am adding a new page to the app, have added this code to the ngRoute section:

```
.when('/settings', {
  templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
  controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
})
```

setting.html exists - verified.
the controller looks like this:

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
   alert("ereer")
   debugger

   $scope.back = function() {      
     $location.path("/users");  
   }
})
```

when navigating to "/settings", while the alert is displaying (and while debugging) i can see the content of settings.html but when i press continue it disappears and my ng-view is empty!
any ideas? thanks!

update: i tried fiddler2, there is no error.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console log?

Comment: PHP server side. No errors whatsoever. not even in chrome's console

Comment: You probably have some more code, right?

Answer (score 1):

OK just found the problem: for some reason the only way to get the page to stay in the ng-view is to have a  on it with ng-app and ng-controller defined. if someone can explain this - please do.
thanks for your time!